# How to view the last taken image on a button click from the path stored in database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-camera

I am making a camera app, In this, I can store the images taken from the app. It saves the image in a path which I have created in the database. It works well and also I can get the saved path it is seen by printed statement.

**My Question:**
I don't know how to view the image which I have stored in this path in my frame layout,I have show last taken image of the user.
Please help me,thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have the path, get the path and parse into URI and cast into imageView.

```
ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(new File("give/your/path/from/db").toString()));
```

Comment: can you give me an example i am using frame layout to view image i am new to android please help and thanks for your reply

Comment: instead of frame layout use ImageView. after initialization use above code. it will display your picture if path is valid. If you are still facing problem, show your code.

Comment: i am not having the code get the image from the database i have only checked whether i can the path which i have saved in the database,hence i don't know how to write the coding to view the image lastly taken by the user.thanks for your reply

Comment: i have taken the coding from this site by using the SurfaceView www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm.

Comment: "It works well and also I can get the saved path it is seen by printed statement." show the code where you have done in the "quoted text.

Comment: // image path
   picture = mediastoredir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
     + timestamp + ".jpg";
   helper.open();

   m.setsavepath(picture);
   m.setobjecttype(image);
   helper.adddetail(m);

Comment: Here helper is the database

Comment: exactly, now you need to fetch the last record and when you get the record, extract path and use my code to set image from the retrieved path.

Comment: yes i don't know how to do the thing you say above please help me and thanks for your reply

Comment: protected void getImage() { // To open up a gallery browser
  System.out.println("----getImage()--");
  onPause();

  // System.out.println("----cameraObject.release--");
  Intent intent = new Intent(image);
  intent.setType("image/*");
  intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

  startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
    1);
  // To handle when an image is selected from the browser, add the
  // following to your Activity
  System.out.println("----getImage()is finish--"+intent);

 }

Comment: here i used this code for viewing the images in gallery but i dont need to view other images in that button while i clicking i have to view the last taken image

Comment: thanks for your code and i have another error is while running the app in tablet it shows Nullpointer onCreate and also error like01-28 18:14:07.410: E/AndroidRuntime(28670):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
please help me

Comment: Thanks for your reply i have question . that is how i can display the timer while starting recording, i don't know to do. while click record the timer as to run and while stop it should stop recording thanks in advance

Comment: you an use `chronometer` for this purpose. It ha `start()` and `stop()` methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,can you give me the coding please i am not having idea for that please help me

Comment: @hari no. you have to try something. if you face any problem in doing so then SO will have help in that.